# XML Schema: require an element to be present when another is present

Tags: xsd

My Schema allows a specific element to be optional, but when I encounter a different also optional element later on in the file, I need the previous one to be present. How can I ensure this via XSD?

Example:

```
<settings>
  <file name="narf.txt"/>
  <metafile name="narf.meta"/>
  <filtermeta>true</filtermeta>
</settings>
```

should be valid,

```
<settings>
  <file name="narf.txt"/>
  <metafile name="narf.meta"/>
</settings>
```

and

```
<settings>
  <file name="narf.txt"/>
</settings>
```

should be valid too,

```
<settings>
  <file name="narf.txt"/>
  <filtermeta>true</filtermeta>
</settings>
```

should not be valid.

Comment: looks like this is not possible with XML Schema 1.0 - future specifications might allow if-then-else, at least it is being discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following schema definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="settings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="file">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element name="metafile">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="filtermeta" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I've run your first three examples against this schema using xmllint and they validate correctly.  The fourth example fails with:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filtermeta'. One of '{metafile}' is expected.
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks. While this solves the simple example I posted to illustrate my problem, it does not solve the underlying problem, especially not if the elements are further apart in the schema logic and hierarchy. It might be possible to make it work with code duplication, but that's just ugly.

Comment: Agreed.  For the more general case, it would rapidly become pretty unpleasant.  Something like Schematron would be much nicer here - you could relax the XSD, so that it focuses on the basic structure and typing constraints.  Then the 'cross-field' validation rules (e.g. if element 'A' is present, element 'B' must be present) can be written as Schematron rules.

Comment: For example, you could write a Schematron rule for the supplied test case as:
 
    `<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="/settings/filtermeta">
            <assert test="../metafile">If filtermeta is present, metafile must also be present</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>`

Comment: Thanks! Schematron is overkill for my problem, but it sure is nice to know about it!

Answer (score 0):

You could have `filtermeta` as an optional attribute to the `metafile` element.